# CanvasRenderingContext2D.strokeRect still tries to antialias my values, instead of drawing one pixel

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, antialiasing

I'm making a graph, mostly as an exercise. The graph tries to connect values by lines, but if a value cannot be connected, it just draws a pixel.

In the following example, I made sure that `minY`, `maxY` and `pixelX` are all integer values. They actually come from `Int32Array` in my real code.

```
        // some min max range for this X pixel coordinate
        const minY = data[i].min;
        const maxY = data[i].max;
        // if there are multiple values on this X coordinate
        if (maxY - minY > 1) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(pixelX + 0.5, minY + 0.5);
            ctx.lineTo(pixelX + 0.5, maxY + 0.5);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        // otherwise just draw a pixel
        else {
            // if the value was interpolated, it's already colored for this pixel
            if (!valueIsInterpolated) {
                ctx.strokeRect(pixelX + 0.5, minY + 0.5, 1, 1);
            }
        }
```

Of it SHOULD draw a single pixel, but instead, it draws variously shaped rectangles which look REALLY ugly in the graph.

[image]

It would look like this if I remove the `+ 0.5` from the call:

[image]

That's even worse. How can I make sure that `strokeRect` draws EXACTLY ONE pixel? No funny business, no anti-aliasing. Just mark a pixel. Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure your canvas is rendered at its set size? Are you sure you don't have scale set? Are you sure your browser is at 100% zoom (doesn't like so when looking at the text). Also, are you on a high-res screen?  Your pixels are actually made of 4*4 pixels on the screenshots. If so answer to question 1 might be "no", and CSS scaling might be your problem. You could try to scale your canvas size by the devicePixelRatio. And finally, if you want to draw perfect pixels, why aren't you simply using `rect()` and `fill`?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `strokeRect()` which will draw an *outline* of your 1-pixel rectangle meaning you will end up with a half pixel outside in all directions (assuming 1 pixel width of the line) which will need to be anti-aliased.

You'd want to use `fillRect()` instead which will *fill* that 1 pixel area.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
for(let x = 5; x < c.width; x += 10) ctx.fillRect(x, 5, 1, 1);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Compared to using strokeRect() which will "bleed" 0.5 (with line width = 1) in all directions from the vector box (which you don't want):

```js
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
for(let x = 5; x < c.width; x += 10) ctx.strokeRect(x, 5, 1, 1);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

Comment: Not needed for rects (provided line width is aligned with odd numbers), and you will still need to fill as stroke will "bleed" outside the actual vector box so to speak.

Comment: What do you mean? Stroke bleeds only on its *width* (as in 90° of its actual path direction), stroking an oddly *widthed* line on an half pixel vertical or horizontal direction will result in no antialiasing; assuming a butt lineCap.(btw your "in all directions" is wrong)

Comment: Yes, but centered on the box line so if your line is encapsulating a pixel it will bleed outside 0.5 pixel in all direction relative to that line, in this cause anti-aliasing. However *filling* that pixel will fill *inside* the encapsulated area.

Comment: Just run the included code to see the evidence of one pixel with fill vs stroke...

Comment: Ah my bad! they're using strokeRect! I though they were using lineTo as in the first if block... in which case there would not be bleeding and their +0.5 would be correct for X, not Y...

Comment: I did upvote, but actually... What they are doing should result in 2*2px squares, with no antialiasing: They are offsetting the drawn path by 0.5 in both axes (which is correct for a rect), then drawing a 1px square. Since stroke will indeed bleed by half the lineWidth, and still assuming a 1px lineWidth, then all these bled half pixels will end up on int pixel boundaries, resulting in a 2*2px square with no antialias. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXLn7.png (in this image, gray are pixels boundaries, blue rect is the path  with virtually no lineWidth, red is the result of `stroke()`.