# How can I prevent Canvas' stroke pixels to stay crisp on zooming in?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I prevent the stroke on Canvas to stop from breaking

Zoom into the below image with (mouse scroll)

pixels break on the black rectangle drawn [image]

**Edit** : adding `lineWidth/2` pixels to start coordinates fixes the problem

```js
// grab the DOM SVG element that you want to be draggable/zoomable:
const element = document.getElementById('scene');

// and forward it it to panzoom.
panzoom(element);

const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeRect(20.5, 20.5, 150, 100);
```

```css
.imageContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

img {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
}

canvas {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 533px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 126px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.1.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class='imageContainer '>
    <div id="scene">
      <img id='imageHD' src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/57/46/dY3eN1.jpg">
      <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "pixels breaking"?

Comment: Looks like the rect has an opacity

Comment: Possibly related: [CanvasRenderingContext2D.strokeRect still tries to antialias my values, instead of drawing one pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51381558/691711)

Comment: if you want to stroke a thick 1px lineWidth vertical or horizontal line, you need to set it's coords to n.5

Comment: @Kaiido i don't think any of the duplicates tagged answer my question or maybe i didn't understand the other questions propoerly, what does `n.5` mean ?

Comment: @Kaiido wouldnt that move the rectangle? i mean on a small laptop screen it wouldnt make a difference, but my app willl run on Big store Tvs

Comment: That means [`strokeRect(20.5, 20.5, 150, 100);`](https://jsfiddle.net/35ta1g76/) Read the dupe targets carefully. stroke bleeds on both sides of the path. so when you stroke a 1px line at coords x1, y1 , x2, y1 you are actually drawing a rectangle x0.5 y0.5 x1.5y0.5 x1.5y1.5 x0.5y1.5 this is not possivle to draw, so you'll have less opaque pixels on all these coords

Comment: @Kaiido so basically I add  `lineWidth/2` to start coordinates everytime ? Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2):

You could try turning anti-aliasing off for your canvas using

```
canvas {
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

The line seems more solid now.

```js
// grab the DOM SVG element that you want to be draggable/zoomable:
const element = document.getElementById('scene');

// and forward it it to panzoom.
panzoom(element);

const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
```

```css
.imageContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto
}

img {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
}

canvas {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 533px;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 126px;
}
canvas {
    image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@8.1.0/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div class='imageContainer '>
    <div id="scene">
      <img id='imageHD' src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/57/46/dY3eN1.jpg">
      <canvas id='myCanvas'></canvas>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @dota2pro [It doesn't look like it works for IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: and I see you are overwrting the same css propoerty    ` image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    image-rendering: pixelated;` so i use only `pixelated` ? I mean you are assinging `image-rendering` twice

Comment: @dota2pro It's a fallback in case either is not supported.

Comment: and now stroke a circle or a triangle...

Comment: @Kaiido ya actually this makes it even more pixelated